# How can I trigger 2 transforms one after the other with a delay in CSS?

Tags: html, css, button, transform

I'm making a menu button with 3 bars (sometimes referred to as a hamburger button) that turns into an X when clicked. I can't figure out how to trigger 2 transforms in one element without them triggering at the same time for the animation.

This script kind of works, but they both trigger at the same time:

```
transform: translate(10px, 10px) rotate(45deg);
```

My goal is for the translate to complete, and then the rotate to start after. (I need to use transitions because they are spam-proof, unlick keyframe animations.) One thing I've tried is putting something like this instead:

```
transform: translate(10px, 10px);
transform: rotate(45deg);
```

But only the bottom one activates. To fix this, I added this:

```
transition: transform 0.4s 0.4s, rotate 0.4s 0.4s;
```

to the mix, but that only added a delay to one of the transforms, still leaving the other broken. My last idea was to use `rotate(deg)` instead of `translate(px)` but there doesn't seem to be a way to center the rotation. I can post my full code if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `translate` and `rotate` as separate CSS properties:

```css
.foo {
  transition: translate 1s 1s, rotate 1s 0s;
}

.foo:focus {
  transition: translate 1s 0s, rotate 1s 1s;
  translate: 10px 10px;
  rotate: 45deg;
}
```

```html
<button class="foo">Focus me for a demo</button>
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! One more question: How can I reverse the movement back to the original position? For example if in your test the button rotated and then moved back into place after being unfocused. (Also I can't vote up because of new account, but pretend I did lol)

Comment: @TheDudeofDC sure, just invert the transition delays for the state. Edited my answer. You don't need to vote up, you can always read [tour].